# How to convert this lists of dicts to a new dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanna convert this list of dicts:

```
input_list = [
    {'a': 5,'b': 7},
    {'a': 3,'b': 4},
]
```

to this:

```
result_dict = {
    'a': [5, 3],
    'b': [7, 4]
}
```

I somehow can't manage to do this.

Can someone help me out there please.

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: You should `groupBy` key.

Comment: Furthermore this problem is underspecified. What if one of the keys does not occur in every dictionary?

Comment: Is pandas work for you ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem posted my solution, thanks for helping me

Comment: @ThinkTeamwork: you're welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## A *vanilla* Python approach

```
result = {}
for subdic in data:
    for k, v in subdic.items():
        result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Here we iterate over the items and we add an empty list to the `result` dict in case the key is not yet in the dictionary. Regardless whether there was already a list, we append `v` to that list.

## Using `defaultdict`

We can make it more elegant by using `defaultdict` from `collections`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for subdic in data:
    for k, v in subdic.items():
        result[k].append(v)
```

Here we basically make abstraction of the `setdefault` (and we also save on constructing useless empty lists). In case the output should be a `dict` (and not a `defaultdict`), we can end the function with:

```
result = dict(result)
```

## Using `pandas`

If every dictionary contains the same keys, we can use pandas:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

result = DataFrame(data).to_dict(orient='list')
```

Comment: Thank you Willem! All 3 snippets work like a charm.

I'm impressed that there are so many nicer and cleaner ways to do it. Gotta love python for this (and this comm for being so helpful).

Comment: @ThinkTeamwork: yes, Python provides some flexibility to define most problems rather elegantly :)

Answer (score 2):

```
result_dict = {}
for index, row_dict in enumerate(input_list):
    for key, item_dict in row_dict.items():
        if not key in result_dict:
            result_dict[key] = []

        result_dict[key].append(row_dict[key])
```

hmm I think this does it. maybe someone comes up with a better approach..

Answer (score 2):

So here is something that might help you.

It uses `defaultdict` construct and that might be an overkill, but it cleanly solves the task.

```
from collections import defaultdict

input_list = [
    {'a': 5, 'b': 7},
    {'a': 3, 'b': 4},
]

result_dict = defaultdict(list)

for i, j in zip(*[i.items() for i in input_list]):
    result_dict[i[0]].append(i[1])
    result_dict[j[0]].append(j[1])

print dict(result_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [1]: input_list = [
   ...:     {'a': 5,'b': 7},
   ...:     {'a': 3,'b': 4},
   ...: ]

In [2]: result_dict = {}

In [3]: for d in input_list:
   ...:     for k, v in d.items():
   ...:         if k not in result_dict:
   ...:             result_dict[k] = [v]
   ...:         else:
   ...:             result_dict[k].append(v)
   ...:             

In [4]: result_dict
Out[4]: {'a': [5, 3], 'b': [7, 4]}
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner

```
{y[0][0]: list(zip(*y)[1]) for y in zip(*[x.items() for x in input_list])}
```

A bit risky, we heavily rely on `.items()` returning keys in the same order each time.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more verbose solution but this also works:

```
from itertools import groupby
from itertools import chain
from operator import itemgetter

input_list = [
    {'a': 5,'b': 7},
    {'a': 3,'b': 4},
]

all_lsts = sorted(chain.from_iterable(d.items() for d in input_list))

group = dict((k, list(map(itemgetter(1), g))) for _, g in groupby(all_lsts, key=itemgetter(0)))

print(group)
# {'a': [3, 5], 'b': [4, 7]}
```